# Conditional inside of MAX sql

Tags: sql, pandas

I'm trying to get the most recent date of a show a band has played in reference to the current date

Ideally I could do something like this but it doesn't work

```
SELECT max(date <= '11-24-2021') as lastShowDate
```

Here are the relevant parts of the query, currently returns the max date of all events we have for the current band, which could be well into the future.

```
SELECT b.bandId, b.bandGuid, b.bandName, e.venue AS lastVenue, e.venueGuid AS lastVenueGuid, 
max(date) as lastShowDate, FROM band AS b
LEFT JOIN eventsBand eb ON eb.bandId = band.bandId    
JOIN events e ON e.eventId = eb.eventId
```

Comment: (1) `date` is a reserved word in MySQL. If you cannot use another field name - escape it with back-ticks.  (2) You can add your date condition into `ON` of your `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write just

```
SELECT date <= '11-24-2021'
```

you can see that it returns like boolean list with 0s and 1s. So taking the max of it just shows that if any row is 1 (if you have any date less than 24th Nov)

If you want to take max date which is less than 24th Nov, you should put it either on your join or where condition